# How to see the event notification from s3 to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Where do I see the event notification sent (the json structure event) from S3 to lambda in the case a lambda function is triggered by an S3 event. It is possible to capture that in cloudwatch?

Comment: It is passed as a parameter when your Lambda function is invoked. If you log the `event` object in your Lambda function, then you will have that in CloudWatch Logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the S3 event notification is passed as the `event` argument to your Lambda handler.

This isn't logged *automatically* anywhere (unlike general invocation information like request ID, memory size, memory usage etc).

To view the event, you need to *manually* log this in your Lambda & then view it in CloudWatch.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the answer to your question is simple...
Use print(event) to post it to the CloudWatch logs of the function.

Create a lambda function:

```py
def handler_name(event, context): 
    print(event)
```

Configure this function to be triggered on an S3-upload.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html